# Возможность xss-атаки, если несуществующая страница отдаёт 200-й статус

Tags: javascript, http, кэширование, cdn

Как злоумышленник может провести атаку, при следующем сценарии?

Допустим, происходит кэширование несуществующей страницы, у которой 200-й статус. Таким образом, если адрес несуществующей страницы выглядит следующим образом **www.another-domain.xyz/image666.jpg**, и к этому урлу можно добавить какой-нибудь параметр/параметры, например...:

- **www.another-domain.xyz/image666.jpg?param=123**
- **www.another-domain.xyz/image666.jpg?param=124**
- **www.another-domain.xyz/image666.jpg?param=125**

...то можно создать ссылку, которой еще не было в веб-приложении, и (возможно) которая попадёт в кэш. В таком случае атакующий сможет провести xss-атаку, подгрузив на кэшированный урл [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)-код со своего ресурса, тем самым осуществив [xss](/questions/tagged/xss) на пользователя, ссылку на которую он даст жертве.

---

У меня имеется 4 вопроса:

**Q0**: В каком случае сервер отвечает на несуществующую информацию 200-ым
статусом?

**Q1**: Объясните, как работает данная атака.

**Q2**: Почему важно на несуществующие страницы отдавать [http-status-code-404](/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404)?

**Q3**: Как происходит механизм кэширования несуществующей страницы на сервере?

---

Апдейт: после долгих поисков мне всё-же удалось найти [PoC](https://bo0om.ru/web-cache-deception-attack) xss-атаки через кэш. 
 Вопреки ответам, XSS через кэш можно осуществить. Спасибо за ответы!

Да, вопрос я написал не совсем корректно, поскольку сам не понимал механизма атаки. Но награжу соткой кого-нибудь, кто даст ответ, после публикования PoC. А существующие ответы мне не понравились!

Comment: Каким образом злоумышленик подгрузит свой код в кеш на ваш сервер?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, вот тут пока сказать не могу. Но думаю, что подгрузить код исключительно потому, что урл закэшировался - не получится однозначно!

Comment: Следовательно, если есть возможность загрузить свой код на чужой сервер, то кеширование и не важно. А если возможности нету, то и кеширование безопасно. Впрочем, я не специалист по безопасности. Будем ждать ответа специалиста, если таковой найдется)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko - мы не говорим о "просто загрузить свой код на чужой сервер". Тут вопрос относительно кэширования несуществующей страницы с 200-ым статусом, и как следствие - атака через такое поведение.

Comment: Каким образом будет атака через кеширование несуществующей страницы?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko извините, я пока не понимаю механизма атаки. Мне её продемонстрировал человек; как она устроена - я написал (описание приближено к действительной атаке). А вот детали, к сожалению, пока не знаю.

Comment: Эх, надо было того человека расспросить подробности! Спасибо за ответы. Очень интересно узнать способ.

Comment: Что подразумевается под кешем несуществующей страницы? Если страница не существует, нет адреса на нее на сервере, нет вообще ничего о ней на сервере, то для какой цели есть кеш на эту страницу? Видимо вы, неправильно, что-то объясняете. Либо дырка на сервере в роутере страниц и видимо, там где есть картинки, можно исполнять скрипты, что рекомендуется закрывать от пользовательских файлов, которые можно подделать..

Comment: @And, как я понял - страницы нет, и кэша на неё нет. Но! если найти несуществ. страницу с 200-ым ответом, и добавить пареметр в урл, то сервер закэширует (когда-нибудь) такой урл, (в вопросе 3 примера такого урла, вот. Какой-то один урл (из примера, с параметрами) попадёт в кэш - остальные нет. Как-то так. Или я чего-то неправильно понял в том, как происходит кэширование?

Comment: Не правильно то, что ваш сервер на несуществующую информацию отвечает 200 статусом и вообще, что либо делает. Правильно будет отдавать 404 или еще лучше 302 =)

Comment: @And в каком случае сервер отвечает на несуществ. информацию 200-ым статусом?

Comment: В случае, если посчитал, что запрос успешно отработал и нет никаких проблем с открытием адреса, а также если вы самостоятельно указываете заголовки с 200 статусом.

Comment: Если речь идёт о веб-приложении и выдаче 200 статуса несуществующей странице, значит в вашем примере все URL переходы обрабатывает некий скрипт-роутер. Роутеров много разных и уязвимости у каждого свои, конкретного ответа дать не получится.

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что _выполнится xss атака_? Если подставить параметр в `url`, то само выполняться ничего все равно не будет, для этого должна быть  уязвимость в самом приложении и сервер тут не причем

Comment: @ThisMan, есть одно но, если адрес отвечает статусом 200, а в ответ ничего не возвращает - это нонсенс, мы сможем засунуть в тело, что угодно. И как-раз, сервер то и причем. Так-как именно он отдает статус на данный запрос по адресу. И если четко не указать в настройках веб-сервера или ручками не прописать нот-фоунды на несуществующие страницы, сможем подделать запрос.

Comment: Q0: если сервер ответил 200 значит страница существует.

Comment: Отдавать 200 на несуществующую страницу это плоховато, но при чём тут безопасность и откуда возьмётся XSS, я так и не понял

Comment: @And _мы сможем засунуть в тело, что угодно_ каким образом это возможно? Вот нам пришел ответ 200 и что с ним делать? Как вставить вредоносный скрипт? Как передать его жертве?

Comment: Q3: С точки зрения SEO. Есть способ опустить сайт в выдаче поисковых систем, загнав в индекс множество страниц с этого сайта с дублирующим или пустым контентом. Страницы со статусом 200 индексируются поисковиками, а с 404 нет.

Comment: Что за сайт вы там с другом взламывали? Дайте ссылку, чтобы разобраться, желательно не инфицированную.

Comment: @misdeed POC, который вы добавили в конце, не имеет никакого отношения к вашему оригинальному вопросу. Это использование уязвимости конкретного приложения (вставка HOST на страницу), и для этой атаки не требуется отдача 200 кода на несуществующий ресурс. И, кстати, менять вопрос после того, как на него даны ответы - нехорошо. Особенно если на вопросе висит конкурс.

Answer (score 9):

Это атака никак не работает. По одной простой причине - с точки зрения HTTP протокола нет понятия "страница существует на сервере". И вообще нет понятия страниц.

Фраза "сервер отдает 200 на несуществующую страницу" просто не имеет смысла.

Клиент посылает запрос. Сервер присылает в ответ код, заголовки и тело. Если код 200 - значит запрос был успешно обработан. Если код 404 - значит запрошенный ресурс на сервере не найден.

Клиенту все равно, почему именно сервер вернул 200 - потому что там на диске лежит файл-страница или потому что на сервере отработал какой-то код, который сгенерировал контент и отдал его в теле ответа.

Ваше описание атаки сводится к "подгрузив на кэшированный урл javascript-код со своего ресурса". Это замечательное действие требует одного из трех условий:

- у атакующего есть прямой доступ к кэшу браузера (т.е. он уже получил доступ на запись к файловой системе клиента).
- не используется https и у атакующего есть доступ к проси по дороге. Тогда он просто может менять трафик, кэширование и 404 ни при чем.
- у атакующего есть доступ к серверу и он может просто подменить контент.

Ответы на вопросы :

1. В случае,  когда разработчик сайта счел это нужным. Отдать 200 - означает всего лишь "запрос обработан, ответ в теле".
2. Никак.  Она не работает.
3. Потому что это единственный стандартный способ сказать клиенту "тут ничего нет"
4. Никак, потому что в сервера обычно не работают в терминах "страниц".

---

Топикастер сослался на https://www.securitylab.ru/analytics/485829.php (оригинал: http://omergil.blogspot.com/2017/02/web-cache-deception-attack.html)

Эта атака действительно использует кэширование, но требует соблюдения двух условий:

1. Серверный код должен выдавать содержимое реальной страницы с персональными / секретными данными вместо 404. Т.е. в ответ на запрос вида `/somepage.php/nonexistent.css` сервер должен отдавать `/somepage.php`. Судя по всему, это поведение PHP по умолчанию, и возможное поведение старых ASP.NET WebForms при некоторых нестандартных настройках.
2. По дороге к серверу должен стоять reverse proxy, с кривыми настройками кэширования - он должен игнорировать отдаваемые сервером заголовки cache control, игнорировать content type, и кэшировать все, что заканчивается на `*.js` / `*.css`

В таком случае сервер может отдать приватную страницу по url с CSS на конце, а криво настроенный прокси - может ее закэшировать.

Это не "уязвимость из-за 404". Это ошибка конфигурации - владелец ресурса сам, вручную, приказывает своему собственному прокси игнорировать заголовки кэширования, и кэшировать все подряд, даже то, на чем прямо написано "приватное, кэшировать нельзя!".

Ошибки конфигурации, к сожалению, случаются. Например, тот же ARR кэширует содержимое запроса целиком, включая заголовок Set-Cookie. Если серверное приложение ставит куки в ответ на статику - например, если это ASP.NET приложение со включенным `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`, который гуглится в качестве костыля для ASP.NET MVC 5 - то ARR может закэшировать установку авторизационной куки Web Forms.

Тем не менее, это не какая-то уязвимость, которой автоматом подвержены все сайты, возвращающие 200 вместо 404. Проблема тут скорее в криво настроенном кэшировании, а не в самом коде ответа.

---

POC, который топикастер упомянул в новой версии вопроса опять же, использует кэширование только как средство доставки, и для полноценной атаки требуется наличие приложения, которое подставляет полученный заголовок HOST в тело ответа. Это дает достаточно широкие возможности по манипуляции контентом - включая загрузку скриптов на страницу.

Если точнее, то ошибок для успешной атаки должно быть несколько:
- Приложение должно рендерить абсолютные пути к статике, подставляя в них текущий HOST.
- Кэш должен быть настроен исходя из предположения, что у сайта ровно один hostname, и кэшировать все в общую кучу.
- Ссылку на отравленную страницу все еще нужно как-то доставить целевому пользователю

Вот только для этой атаки никак не требуется, чтобы сервер отвечал на несуществующие страницы 200-м кодом, и к первоначальному вопросу это дополнение никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Думаю, что "у атакующего есть доступ к серверу и он может просто подменить контент." можно добиться использую технику кэширования 200-ых ответов. Дело в том, что я этот вопрос не из головы придумал, а мне данную атаку демонстрировал один товарищ, на одном ресурсе. Именно почти описанным способом, он получил куки юзера. Спасибо за ответ, но он не годится.

Comment: @misdeed тогда у меня два возможных объяснения (1) вы не так поняли суть атаки. (2) товарищ, демонстрировавший атаку, просто вам соврал. Вы просите обосновать бессмысленную с точки зрения технологии вещь. Почти все сайты кэшируют отдаваемые с 200-м кодом скрипты. Добавляйте к ним гет-параметры, "подгружайте на кэшированный урл javascript-код" - и вперед, вы взломаете весь интернет.

Comment: Ну вот у меня имеется ссылке, если вам интересно: https://www.securitylab.ru/analytics/485829.php (ничего особенного, и детали атаки не раскрываются), но атаковать через кэширование - возможно. Хотелось бы узнать, как именно организовать атаку через кэширование.

Comment: извините, но ваш ответ по большей степени не несёт в себе ответа на вопрос об xss через кэширование.

Comment: @misdeed если вы бы внимательнее прочитали статью по ссылке, то заметили бы, что там две атаки (1) используется подмена контента при работе по http - и про это есть вот прямо в моем ответе. (2) используется действительно некорректная настройка кэширования отдаваемых секретных данных без заголовка cache control: private (скорее всего отдается cache control: public, который позволяет кэшировать ответ и отдавать его всем). Т.е. суть "уязвимости" - оказывается, если работать без шифрования и поставить на секретных данных "можно видеть всем" - то их будут видеть все. 200 код там всего лишь триггер

Comment: @misdeed и, технически, обе "атаки" - не xss. Это просто (1) подмена трафика, MitM. (2) ошибка конфигурации, разработчик сам разрешил досуп к приватным данным другим людям.

Comment: Хорошо. Пусть ответ будет. Если найду PoC на русском, отвечу на свой вопрос. По ссылке есть видео на конфу Black Hat, но английский у меня плохой.

Comment: Да, и за минус (если это вы, конечно) огромнейшее человеческое спасибо!

Comment: @misdeed не совсем понял, причем тут английский, PoC на русском и минус?. По вашей ссылке проблема безопасности, вызванная тем,  что сервер не просто отвечает 200-м кодом на "несуществующую страницу", а тем, что сервер вместо css отдает реальную страницу с приватными данными, и с заголовками вида "можно положить в публичный кэш". Могу дописать это в ответ, если вам это поможет

Comment: @misdeed добавьте в вопрос полные шаги атаки и ресурс, где это проводилось. То что кто-то вам сказал, что это `xss-атака` через кэш, еще ничего не значит. Попробуйте даже загуглить _xss-атака через кэш_, ничего толкового не найдете

Answer (score 0):

> В таком случае атакующий сможет провести xss-атаку, подгрузив на
>   кэшированный урл javascript-код со своего ресурса, тем самым
>   осуществив xss на пользователя, ссылку на которую он даст жертве.

Давайте для начала разберемся, что такое `xss-атака`

Допустим у нас есть такой `html`:

```
<div>
    <h1 id='title'></h1>
</div>
```

И вот такой `js` код:

```
// получаем параметр title из строки вида site.com?title=Заголовок
const titleFromUrl = location.search.replace('\?', '').split('=')[1];
const title = document.getElementId('title');
title.innerHTML = titleFromUrl;
```

В чем проблема такого кода и как осуществить тут `xss` атаку?

Мы вставляем значение в `title` через `innerHTML`, это значит, что там может оказаться любой валидный `html`, даже тэг `<script>`, который выполнится потом браузером. 
Иначе говоря, мы не проверяем данные, которые получаем, в этом и проблема

```
site.com?title=<script>alert(1)</script> // валидный адрес сайта
```

Теперь давайте вернемся к вашему вопросу.

> подгрузив на кэшированный урл javascript-код со своего ресурса

Каким именно образом злоумышленник сможет подгрузить данные со своего ресурса на сервер? Или на страницу жертвы? Кэш тут не причем, для `xss-атаки` в случае клиентской части, необходима эта самая клиентская часть. Если ваш сервер отдает пустой документ, пусть и с 200 статусом, ни о какой `xss-атака` и речи быть не может, потому что вредоносный код некому будет выполнить.
Если же говорить о серверной части, тогда проблема скорее всего в коде, который обрабатывает запросы, или в `sql-запросах`, например, которые не экранируют данные, приходящие от клиента.

Comment: Простите, но это ваще не то!

Answer (score 0):

Суть атаки описанной в [securitylab.ru/analytics/485829.php](http://securitylab.ru/analytics/485829.php) заключается попадании в кеш персональных данных пользователя путем некорректной настройки кеширующей системы.

Например, при вызове странице http://site.com/profile/123456.css в кеш попадет профиль текущего пользователя. Остается на сайте злоумышленника разместить эту ссылку. Юзер заходит на сайт злоумышленника при этом в кеш попадает его профиль и теперь любой пользователь (включая злоумышленника) по заданой ссылке может увидит конфиденциальную информацию.

Злоумышленник каждому отдельному пользователю генерит свою ссылку и таким образом знает где в кеше искать информацию.

Comment: Описанная атака является CSRF, а не XSS